# List of recently updated tables in database

Tags: sql, database

I have multiple tables in my database.
I need to know the names of tables updated after some timestamp (or during last action).

Can you please guide me with links for the query or any help?

Comment: Which database system? Which version?? This is **very** vendor-specific... (no SQL standard way of doing this)

Comment: Just to clarify my question:I want the all the tables which got updated(insert data) after my action in the database

Comment: @Pradeep: again **which DBMS are you using**?

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from sys.tables order by modify_date desc
```

Assuming this is SQL server.

Comment: How will this determine exact TimeStamp?

Comment: @Gunner - this would not determine TimeStamp. This will give the tables which are most recently updated. Based on timestamp, OP can compare on the modify_date column.

Comment: +1. There's no way to know that they do mean SQL Server, but that's their fault not yours, you acknowledge this, and it's some darn useful knowledge to have that I've no doubt will be blessed when it turns up in the googling of someone pulling their hair out over a similar problem :)

Comment: I think "updated" here means that the structure was modified, not the data.

Comment: Does modify mean change of meta data or change of data?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out...

```
SELECT
    [name],
    create_date,
    modify_date
FROM sys.tables
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

Comment: Hi,
is there any way if I can find out or list the table which have been updated/inserted with new values?

Answer (score -3):

You need to maintain a TimeStamp column in every table to be able to achieve this through a query. 
Assuming you have such column,  look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) for ways to write TimeStamp based query.